# How to fix unsupported operand error in keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

I am trying to use callbacks to stop the iterations if there is no improvement, but facing this error:

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'EarlyStopping' and 'list'
```

Sharing the code which generated the above error.

```
    sgd = krs.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    model.compile(
     optimizer = "sgd",
     loss = "binary_crossentropy",
     metrics = ["accuracy"]
    )

    results = model.fit(
        train_X, train_Y
        ,epochs = 10
        ,batch_size = 100
        ,class_weight = {1:10.11, 0:1}
        ,shuffle = 1
        ,validation_data = (test_X, test_Y)
        ,verbose = 1
        ,callbacks = krs.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta = 0, patience=2, verbose=0, mode="auto")
    )
```

Comment: callbacks is a list of callbacks, not a single instance.

Comment: Yes, and I am using EarlyStopping one in my code. forgot to mention it in the description section

Comment: Then it should be callbacks = [ krs.callbacks.EarlyStopping(...) ]

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked.